# I have a baseball card table. My SQL database design was going swimmingly until I remembered that cards can have more than one player on them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the longer version:
I have a table that is designed to hold records of baseball cards.

- id BIGINT IDENTITY
- card_number NVARCHAR(MAX)
- player ???
- set_id INT
- is_Rookie BIT
- is_autographed BIT
- is_relic BIT
- print_run INT
- notes TEXT

What I'm struggling with is the "player." If every card only had one player, I'd link it to the player table with an id.  Easy.

Because cards can have multiple players, I've created a card_player table:

- id BIGINT IDENTITY
- card_id BIGINT
- player_id BIGINT

Now I want to query the card table, and get a list of the players that are on the card, in one record. Have any thoughts on how I should re-arrange my data structures, or the best way to write a query that can pull this together?

| ID | Card Number | Players | Set ID | Rookie? | Auto? | Relic? | Print Run | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | SCMB-7 | A, C, B | 1904 | True | True | True | 499 |  |

Comment: Side note: your `card_player` table does not need a separate `id` column, it should have a composite primary key of the other two columns. And `nvarchar(max)` is a rather large size for a short identifier column (which should probably be the primary key anyway)